# bootstrap close all open modals prior to opening a new one

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a situation where I'm using a number of modals (for a login form, for a registration form, for a pass retrieval form, etc.) What happens is that if the user clicks "login" and then "register" they'll get two modals on top of each other. I would like bootstrap to be automatically closing all open modals prior to opening a new one. Ideally also wait for the animation.

Has anyone done anything? I have the following solution but I need to target the function every time.

```
function close_modal() {
    $('.modal').modal('hide')
}
```

How can I bind this to every modal that opens?

I'm using **Bootstrap v3.3.4**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to Bootstrap's website

> Multiple open modals not supported
>   Be sure not to open a modal while another is still visible. Showing more than one modal at a time requires custom code.

I tried to open multiple modals at the same time using javascript, which leads to the second modal not responding to events such as clicks.

So you will not get two multiple modals showing at the same time if you just click on the web page.

Here's the link
[Bootstrap Modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

============edited here===============

You can try this

```
$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    $('.modal').not($(this)).each(function () {
        $(this).modal('hide');
    });
});
```

So before a modal is showing up, this script will try to close all other modals.

Here is the test html I used.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Modal Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal_1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Title1</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Body1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="launchSecond">Second</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal_2">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Title2</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Body2</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="launchFirst">First</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="launchModalBtn">Launch Modal</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).on('click','#launchModalBtn',function () {
            $('#modal_1').modal();
        });

        $(document).on('click', '#launchSecond', function () {
            $('#modal_2').modal();
        })

        $(document).on('click', '#launchFirst', function () {
            $('#modal_1').modal();
        })

        $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
            $('.modal').not($(this)).each(function () {
                $(this).modal('hide');
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: that is correct. It doesn't respond to clicks but it is still in the background. I would like it to be closed. I've read that quote from the website I wonder why there is no check if there is already a modal that is open -> close that modal and then open a new one..

Comment: KenKenKen that's great! Thanks. I wonder why this is not part of the modal flow.

Comment: @Ando Glad I can help!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use this solution for entire site:

```
$('body').on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
    $('.modal:visible').removeClass('fade').modal('hide').addClass('fade');
});
```

It's necessary to remove class `fade` (and add it later) to avoid scrolling issue of new shown popup. If not - you couldn't scroll it :(

Comment: This helped me. This should be marked as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with vanilla JS you can do the following for Bootstrap V5:

```
// import all your dependencies
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap"

// close all modals but the one you want to open
const $modals =  document.querySelectorAll('.modal')
$modals.forEach(modal => {
  modal.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function() {
    $modals.forEach(_modal => {
      let currentModal = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(_modal)
      if (this !=_modal && currentModal) currentModal.hide()
    })
  })
})
```